# Telerik RadDataPager Page Routing Navigation Links

Tags: asp.net, routes, telerik, raddatapager

I have a routed page url for raddatapager and after I have updated to Q2 2013 the RadDataPager creates navigation pages like this

```
www.mysite.com/quotes/1_25      -> {page_pagesize} <- NOT OK!
```

instead of

```
www.mysite.com/quotes/1         -> {page} <- OK
```

25 is the page size, but I don't want it there ! How can I remove it from RadDataPager links?

This is the code I use for RadDataPager

```
  <telerik:RadDataPager ID="RadDataPager1" runat="server" 
                                          RouteName="QuoteTopic" RoutePageIndexParameterName="PageIndex" AllowRouting="True" PagedControlID="RadListView1"  
                                          PageSize="25" Skin="MetroTouch" EnableViewState="False" OnPageIndexChanged="RadDataPager1_PageIndexChanged" AllowSEOPaging="True" SEOPagingQueryPageKey="RadListView1">
                        <Fields>
            <telerik:RadDataPagerButtonField FieldType="FirstPrev" />
            <telerik:RadDataPagerButtonField FieldType="Numeric" />
            <telerik:RadDataPagerButtonField FieldType="NextLast" />
            <telerik:RadDataPagerTemplatePageField>
                <PagerTemplate>
                    <div style="float: right">
                        <b>Quotes
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="CurrentPageLabel" Text="<%# Container.Owner.StartRowIndex + 1 %>" />
                            to
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="TotalPagesLabel" Text="<%# Container.Owner.StartRowIndex + Container.Owner.PageSize %>" />
                            of
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="TotalItemsLabel" Text="<%# Container.Owner.TotalRowCount %>" /> <br /> </b>
                    </div>
                </PagerTemplate>
            </telerik:RadDataPagerTemplatePageField>
        </Fields>
                    </telerik:RadDataPager>
```

Why I need this ? Because I don't need the page size in the URL and all my pages are indexed by google as mysite.com/quotes/{page}  and changing it to mysite.com/quotes/{page_pagesize} will hurt to site ranking as all pages need to be re-indexed by google.

Thanks !